# Sending AJAX request to submit the form in a commandButton that have an action

Tags: ajax, jsf-2

In my page, i have a form, wich components get it's values from the managedBean.
Then, ther is this button in the page:

```
<p:commandButton value="Search" action="#{mbProduct.selectBrand}" ajax="false" immediate="true" />
```

What this button does is, when i click, it redirects the user to the Brands page, so he can choose the product's brand and return to the product page(exactly the same way when the user clicked on the button).
The problem is, if i change any value of the inputTexts in the form, and immediatly click the "Search" button, that value of the inputText is not sent to the managedBean, because there is no ajax request to do it before the user clicks the Search button.
How can i avoid this behavior and set the field values before the button call his action?

---EDIT---
As Alexandre suggested, i taked out the immediate="true" from the button, but now i have a validation error.
The specific validation it's in this field:

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{myMb.selectedItem}">
<f:selectItems value="#{myMb.itemsList}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

The itemsList is lazily initialized in the myMb constructor, and the validation error occurs only if the user don't change the selectedValue. if he changes this value, the validation error don't happens.

Comment: What is the exact validation error? Does the log give more informations?

Answer (score 0):

You should remove your `immediate="true"` so the inputs will be applied before the action.

More informations : http://balusc.blogspot.ca/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html#WhenShouldIUseTheImmediateAttribute

Comment: It works, but doing this, the components are being validated...
Is there a way to avoid validation in the components, but in the same way try to apply the values of the components that have the correct value?

Comment: You can try <f:validateBean disabled="true"/> on all inputs you don't want to validate

Comment: i think i'm starting to understand this...
but this code don't works. The specific validation it's in this field:
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{myMb.selectedItem}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{myMb.itemsList}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
the itemsList is lazily initialized in the myMb constructor, and the validation error occurs only if the user don't change the selectedValue. if he changes this value, the validation error don't happens.

Comment: yes i put the code in the question. btw, thanks for helping me.

Comment: What is the exact validation error? Does the log give more informations?